# SQL Server query can`t show filter results correctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have sql server query like that:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE company_name = 'Shell'
  and datetime >= '2017-03-06' 
  and datetime <= '2017-03-06' 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Now that code show me all Shell rows even outside of the searched date period.

I want Shell rows only in `2017-03-06`.

Where is my mistake?

This code usually work well in MySQL server.

Comment: Can you provide a repro for us to test

Comment: see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Include, one row of you data at least for us to get better understanding, and what's the type for datetime?

Comment: what about typing `and datetime like '2017-03-06' ` instead of `and datetime >= '2017-03-06' 
and datetime <= '2017-03-06` is it working ?

Answer (score 1):

CAST(datetime  AS DATE) and compare with date only

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE company_name = 'Shell' and CAST(datetime  AS DATE)= '2017-03-06' ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's caused by your server setting for date (it's not using 03 as month, but as day).
Use always

### CONVERT when work with a date (for insert, in where, etc.). Eg. CONVERT(datetime, '2017-03-06',121) if date is in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (ID INT, COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR(10), DATETIME DATETIME)
SELECT * FROM mytable

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1,'Shell', '2017-03-06')
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (2,'Shell', '2017-03-07')
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (3,'Shell', '2017-03-05')
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (4,'Shell', '2017-03-06')


INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (5,'Nut', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-03-06',121))
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (6,'Nut', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-03-07',121))
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (7,'Nut', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-03-05',121))
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (8,'Nut', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-03-06',121))


---Results can be uncorrect
SELECT ID, COMPANY_NAME, DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar,DATETIME,121) AS DATE_STR
FROM mytable
WHERE company_name = 'Shell'
    AND DATETIME >= '2017-03-06'
    AND DATETIME <= '2017-03-06'
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC

---Results correct
SELECT ID, COMPANY_NAME, DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar,DATETIME,121) AS DATE_STR
FROM mytable
WHERE company_name = 'Nut'
    AND DATETIME >= CONVERT(datetime, '2017-03-06',121)
    AND DATETIME <= CONVERT(datetime, '2017-03-06',121)
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE company_name = 'Shell' and datetime like '2017-03-06%' ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE company_name = 'Shell' 
  and datetime >= '2017-03-06' 
  and datetime < '2017-03-07' 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

It will pick up all the rows whose *datetime* is at any point of '2017-03-06'.

Or cast the *datetime* to *date* data type as **Anil Kumar** suggested and then use the `datetime = '2017-03-06'` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing about sql server. "Always consider twice what you write in where criteria" Other answers can solve your problem but the main problem is your algoritm or your logic when coding sql. What you need ? The answer of this question is "specific day" so specify just date. Do not use <>. I see you used these logic for datetime format. So convert to date and then compare. If you do not need hour, minute or something waste them. This logic is always makes simple your problems. best regards.